# php function for adding days, week or month to a date

Tags: php, date, increment, schedule

I'm trying to do a schedule like a loan.

So I have done the following code:

```
function periode($var, $i2)
    {
        if($var=='52')
        {
            echo '"+ '.$i2.' week"';
        }
        if($var=='26')
        {
            echo '"+ ('.$i2.' +1) week"';
        }
        if($var=='12')
        {
            echo '"+ '.$i2.' month"';
        }
        if($var=='6')
        {
            echo '"+ ('.$i2.' +1) month"';
        }
        if($var=='2')
        {
            echo '"+ ('.$i2.' +6) month"';
        }
        if($var=='1')
        {
            echo '"+ ('.$i2.' +12) month"';
        }


    }
 $chaine ="
 <table style='width:100%'>
 <tr>
 <th>Capital Principal</th>
 <th>Date d'&eacute;ch&eacute;ance</th>
 <th>Montant de l'&eacute;ch&eacute;ance</th>
 <th>Capital restant d&ucirc;</th>
 </tr>";
 $i2=0;
 $montant_echeance = round($montant_du / $nombre_echeances, 2);
 $reste=$montant_du ;
 while($i2 <= $nombre_echeances)
 {
     echo  $date =date("d-m-Y", strtotime($debut) .periode($pay_periodicity, $i2));             
        if ($i2 == $nombre_echeances)
        {
                $montnt_echeance = $reste;
                $reste = 0;
        }
     $chaine .= "<tr>
     <td>$montant_du</td>
      <td>".$date."</td>
     <td>$montant_echeance</td>
     <td>$reste</td></tr>'";
           $reste = $reste-$montant_echeance;
     $i2++;
        }
$chaine .="</table>";
print "$chaine";


    }
```

But instead of returning to me the good date, it returns to me:

```
"+ 0 month"11-10-2012"+ 1 month"11-10-2012"+ 2 month"11-10-2012"+ 3 month"11-10-2012"+ 4 month"11-10-2012"+ 5 month"11-10-2012"+ 6 month"11-10-2012"+ 7 month"11-10-2012"+ 8 month"11-10-2012"+ 9 month"11-10-2012"+ 10 month"11-10-2012"+ 11 month"11-10-2012"+ 12 month"11-10-2012"+ 13 month"11-10-2012"+ 14 month"11-10-2012"+ 15 month"11-10-2012"+ 16 month"11-10-2012"+ 17 month"11-10-2012"+ 18 month"11-10-2012"+ 19 month"11-10-2012"+ 20 month"11-10-2012"+ 21 month"11-10-2012"+ 22 month"11-10-2012"+ 23 month"11-10-2012"+ 24 month"11-10-2012"+ 25 month"11-10-2012"+ 26 month"11-10-2012"+ 27 month"11-10-2012"+ 28 month"11-10-2012"+ 29 month"11-10-2012"+ 30 month"11-10-2012"+ 31 month"11-10-2012"+ 32 month"11-10-2012"+ 33 month"11-10-2012"+ 34 month"11-10-2012"+ 35 month"11-10-2012"+ 36 month"11-10-2012"+ 37 month"11-10-2012"+ 38 month"11-10-2012"+ 39 month"11-10-2012"+ 40 month"11-10-2012"+ 41 month"11-10-2012"+ 42 month"11-10-2012"+ 43 month"11-10-2012"+ 44 month"11-10-2012"+ 45 month"11-10-2012"+ 46 month"11-10-2012"+ 47 month"11-10-2012"+ 48 month"11-10-2012"+ 49 month"11-10-2012"+ 50 month"11-10-2012"+ 51 month"11-10-2012"+ 52 month"11-10-2012"+ 53 month"11-10-2012"+ 54 month"11-10-2012"+ 55 month"11-10-2012"+ 56 month"11-10-2012"+ 57 month"11-10-2012"+ 58 month"11-10-2012"+ 59 month"11-10-2012"+ 60 month"11-10-2012 '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Capital Principal   Date d'échéance     Montant de l'échéance   Capital restant dû
6210.04     11-10-2012  103.5   6210.04
6210.04     11-10-2012  103.5   6106.54
6210.04     11-10-2012  103.5   6003.04
6210.04     11-10-2012  103.5   5899.54
6210.04     11-10-2012  103.5   5796.04
6210.04     11-10-2012  103.5   5692.54
6210.04     11-10-2012  103.5   5589.04
```

It is really weird,

I'm a bit lost I really have no Idea of what is wrong with that function.

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Receive all my utmost Respect.

Kind Regards.

SP.

Comment: remove the echo before "$date =date("d-m-Y", strtotime($debut)... "

Comment: Dear Sir I've done that, it still display the same things. Kind Regards; SP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your php code is not well written and it won't work. Since you didn't post the complete code, I don't know how to help. I gave some tips & ideas that will help you:

1. periode() function should return the value, echo won't work
2. modify your code as I mentioned
3. Understand the strtotime() function and php

See my below sample code:

```
function periode($var, $i2)
{
    if($var=='1') {
        return '+'.$i2.' day';
    }
    else if($var=='2') {
        return '+'.$i2.' week';
    }
    else if($var=='3') {
        return '+'.$i2.' month';
    }
}

$current_date = date('Y-m-d');
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(periode(1, 1), strtotime($current_date)));
echo '<br />'.date('Y-m-d', strtotime(periode(2, 2), strtotime($current_date)));
echo '<br />'.date('Y-m-d', strtotime(periode(3, 1), strtotime($current_date)));
```

Comment: dear Sir, thanks for your quick reply, I've tried this $date =date("d-m-Y",  strtotime(periode($pay_periodicity, $i2)), strtotime($debut));       it returns to me Warning: date() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given

Comment: Your periode() does not return valid parameters.

echo '"+ '.$i2.' week"'; 

Above is not the correct one. Modify those as per my code.

Refer this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: dear Sir, using hat modifications it returns to me 01-01-1970 for all dates

Comment: It's wrong with '"+ '.$i2.' week"', etc,. Did you change that to valid parameters?

Just analyze your code and you will be able make it work. Make sure you are passing valid date, and other parameters.

Comment: Dear Sir, in some case I need to concatenate the $i2 + 2

Comment: echo '"+ ('.$i2.' +12) month"';

Concatenate like this: eg: return '+ '.($i2+12).' month';

Answer (score 1):

remove the single quote(`'`) in the following line `<td>$reste</td></tr>'";`

Answer (score 1):

In the function `periode`, replace all the `echo`s with `return`.

Also, I suggest using a `switch` statement instead of lots of `if`s.